# Getting error 404 after setting up SSL Proxy load balancing in Google Cloud

Tags: ssl, google-cloud-platform, load-balancing

I set up SSL Proxy Load Balancing using [official](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl/setting-up-ssl) guide. I have completed every step, but when I visit my domain, I am getting a 404 Not Found response. I am trying to set up SSL on my website, hosted in Google Cloud VM and is accessible via IP of the VM.

Also, in the [Create instances](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl/setting-up-ssl#create_instances) section of that guide, step-6 is unclear to me. Am I supposed to add `ssl-lb` as a network tag?

Answer (score 0):

Of course, if you are creating a firewall rule for the SSL load balancer by specifying Target tas then you must have to create instance with specified tag.

If you look at the section **Create a firewall rule for the SSL load balancer** step 6 you will understand.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the instance With the tag ssl-lb which the firewall rule will use later. You are supposed to add ssl-lb as a target tag while creating the  Firewall rule.

VPC Networks —> Firewall —>While creating firewall rule to allow traffic from load balance to instance you need to create a firewall rule by entering the allow-ssl-lb-and-health add the select network as  default and here you have to set target tags as ssl-lb .

[image]

You can also add ssl-lb as a network tag by using the [Gcloud command line](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl/setting-up-ssl#gcloud).